# Date range filter without SPD or Infopath

Tags: filter

I am having a very difficult time trying to figure out how to create a page in SP2010 Enterprise that displays list items based on a user selected date range and status field is "approved" . Preferably using a pair of date pickers or a single date picker that lets you highlight multiple days.

Something like : where date=> 'end_date' and date=<'start_date' and status=approved

I do not have access to SPD (blocked at the firewall) or Infopath.

I am very new to SP and maybe thinking too hard but this seems like it should be an easy task.

I am not sure what webpart would best fit this, or maybe I need to use a context editor web part and JQuery?

It seems like every answer I find on the internet requires SPD which I cannot access.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Without SPD there isn't much you can do. The only option you have is to write everything in code with JSOM (so basically, retrieve the items with a CAML query, and show the result somehow in html)

Comment: It appears this is not possible? I was really hoping somebody could guide me on using JQuery to accomplish this. It would seem like a simple task to get user input for start date and end date and filter records but without SPD it seems impossible?

Comment: I know it sucks, but I fear it's impossible.